# Excel VBA name error when setting cell formula through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm entering a formula in excel using vba, but I don't get the evaluation in the cell, rather I get a **`#name`** error.

The formula is written correctly, because when I go into the cell and press **`F2+Enter`**, I get the value I'm looking for. I've searched for some ways to do this, but I cannot find an answer that solves my issue.

My formula goes like this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula =  
"=IF(A3="""","""",VLOOKUP(C3,AsignaciónCurvas!$B$5:$R$76,SI(B3=""MXP"",14,SI(B3=""UDI"",15,SI(B3=""USD"",16,1))),0))"
```

I have tried using `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` or  `ActiveCell.value` instead of `ActiveCell.Formula`, but none of them worked. I also found something on the Internet using `SendJey` command like this code:

```
Application.SendKeys "{F2}", True
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
```

When I did this I got a new "window" opened from the vba application and it didn't work either.

Comment: You have both `IF` and `SI`.  Try doing them all in the English version.  Or Change your `.Formula` to `.FormulaLocal` and use all spanish versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, i changed everything to english and worked perfectly well!